# Is there a difference between returning void and null in PHP?

Tags: php, null, void

When I have a function like this:

```
public function getResult() {
    return;
}
```

Is it the exactly same as returning **null**?
And if I'd be doing this:

```
is_null($this->getResult());
```

Would that result in **true**?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: it probably took you longer to write the question than it would to run the code and see for yourself

Comment: There is no `void` in PHP, although an RFC has been proposed for it..... but if the return is omitted (or return is not given a value) then the value NULL will be returned.

Comment: https://github.com/gregoryyoung/nothing/issues/4

Answer (score 21):

In terms of runtime behaviour, no, there is not. All functions implicitly return a `NULL`, and `return` with no value (so `return;`) produces a `NULL` return value.

If you use the `: void` return type declaration in PHP 7.1+, `return NULL;` (instead of `return;`) is forbidden, but this is really just a coding-style restriction. Function calls always produce *some* value in PHP, so `var_dump((function (): void {})());` outputs `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description the following expression

```
is_null($this->getResult());
```

will evaluate to true since function in above mentioned code snippet returns void.

Comment: `void` does not exist in PHP, a [null](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php) will be returned